# 404 on Nginx for non-www

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, no-www

My site is running successfully with [www.site.com](http://www.site.com). I've been reading through similar questions and I'm struggling to get the non-www to load.

Error that I get when requesting site.com rather than www.site.com;
404 Not Found
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

On Linode I have A record for site.com & www.

This is the output from sudo nginx -t

```
    nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
    nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
    # configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
    user www-data;
    worker_processes auto;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;
    include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
    
    events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
    }
    
    http {
    
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
    
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;
    
        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;
    
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
    
        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##
    
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    
        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##
    
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    
        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##
    
        gzip on;
    
        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    
        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##
    
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    }
    
    
    #mail {
    #   # See sample authentication script at:
    #   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
    #
    #   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
    #   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
    #   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4r

ev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/70-mod-stream-geoip2.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_geoip2_module.so;

    # configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:
    
    types {
        text/html                             html htm shtml;
        text/css                              css;
        text/xml                              xml;
        image/gif                             gif;
        image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
        application/javascript                js;
        application/atom+xml                  atom;
        application/rss+xml                   rss;
    
        text/mathml                           mml;
        text/plain                            txt;
        text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
        text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
        text/x-component                      htc;
    
        image/png                             png;
        image/tiff                            tif tiff;
        image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
        image/x-icon                          ico;
        image/x-jng                           jng;
        image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
        image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
        image/webp                            webp;
    
        application/font-woff                 woff;
        application/java-archive              jar war ear;
        application/json                      json;
        application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
        application/msword                    doc;
        application/pdf                       pdf;
        application/postscript                ps eps ai;
        application/rtf                       rtf;
        application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
        application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
        application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
        application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
        application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
        application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
        application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
        application/x-cocoa                   cco;
        application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
        application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
        application/x-makeself                run;
        application/x-perl                    pl pm;
        application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
        application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
        application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
        application/x-sea                     sea;
        application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
        application/x-stuffit                 sit;
        application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
        application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
        application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
        application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
        application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
        application/zip                       zip;
    
        application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
        application/octet-stream              deb;
        application/octet-stream              dmg;
        application/octet-stream              iso img;
        application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;
    
        application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
        application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
        application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;
    
        audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
        audio/mpeg                            mp3;
        audio/ogg                             ogg;
        audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
        audio/x-realaudio                     ra;
    
        video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
        video/mp2t                            ts;
        video/mp4                             mp4;
        video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
        video/quicktime                       mov;
        video/webm                            webm;
        video/x-flv                           flv;
        video/x-m4v                           m4v;
        video/x-mng                           mng;
        video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
        video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
        video/x-msvideo                       avi;
    }
    
    # configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flaskblog:
    server {
        server_name www.site.com site.com;
    
        location /static {
            alias /home/falvey/FlaskApp/blog/static;
        }
    
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.site.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.site.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    
    }
    server {
        if ($host = www.site.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
    
        listen 80;
        server_name www.site.com site.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    
    
    }
    
    # configuration file /etc/nginx/proxy_params:
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    
    # configuration file /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:
    # This file contains important security parameters. If you modify this file
    # manually, Certbot will be unable to automatically provide future security
    # updates. Instead, Certbot will print and log an error message with a path to
    # the up-to-date file that you will need to refer to when manually updating
    # this file.
    
    ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
    
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384";
```

Comment: please share the whole NGINX configuration. I am interested in the `server_name` directives value ;) But 404 not found means your DNS is working as it should be. Your request hits the NGINX web server. Which is step one out of many.

Comment: That last `server` block in your question returns 404.

Comment: Thats a default certbot configuration injected using the nginx plugin. Thats totally fine though.

Comment: @TimoStark not really fine, as it returns 404 for `http://example.com`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. A couple of more questions: Whats the directory content of `sites-enabled` and where is your certbot generated config-file? `conf.d`? Another idea (before doing all that manually) is to post the output of `sudo nginx -T`. This will dump the whole configuration currently loaded. Please share this one. This will help me / us finding the issue.

Comment: @TimoStark Thanks for the sudo command, I was naively unaware of this. I've included the output which will hopefully shine a light on where I'm going wrong.

Comment: So yes @RichardSmith was totaly right in this case! Sorry. I have just checked my certbot config. I had the same issue with non-www and www in the http (80) server block. Will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` block inside the certbot managed server block will just capture the `www.example.com` server name and redirect that to the https server block.

To do the same for non-www

configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flaskblog:

```
server {
        if ($host = www.example.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
    
        if ($host = example.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com example.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    
    
    }
```

OR if you prefer one if block

```
  if ($host ~* ^(www\.)?example.com$) {
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
```

This will redirect all non-www http traffic to https://example.com/$uri. If you want to redirect to `https://www.example.com` change the `return` to

`return 301 $https://www.$host$request_uri`

Comment: This did it, thanks so much Timo! I think I had tried something whereby I had done the same but in a separate server block which wasn't working. You've cured a longstanding headache, very grateful.